# Adding a connected wcf reference to dependency injection in .net

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, wcf, soap, dependency-injection

I am working on a .net 6 API which needs to consume a SOAP service, which I have generated by adding as a connected service in visual studio. In my API, I have a controller which has a service class as a dependency and in that service I am calling the soap service. I want to add this generated soap service as a dependency to my service class but I am having issues figuring out how to do this. Is this achievable?

Example of what generated code for the connected service.
https://pastebin.pl/view/1e29b3e5

Comment: Please add all code relevant to your question as part of your post on StackOverflow. Make it as easy as possible for others to help you.

Comment: @Steven I don't have much else to provide in terms of relevant code. Given this generated soap service that I provided in the pastebin, how can I add it to dependency injection?

Comment: Hi Rusty, the link is expired. Could you share more details ？